# How to receive uploaded file with Klein like Flask in python

Tags: python, web-services, klein-mvc

When setting up a Flask server, we can try to receive the file user uploaded by

```
imagefile = flask.request.files['imagefile']
filename_ = str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(' ', '_') + \
    werkzeug.secure_filename(imagefile.filename)
filename = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename_)
imagefile.save(filename)
logging.info('Saving to %s.', filename)
image = exifutil.open_oriented_im(filename)
```

When I am looking at the `Klein` documentation, I've seen `http://klein.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/staticfiles.html`, however this seems like providing file from the webservice instead of receiving a file that's been uploaded to the web service. If I want to let my `Klein` server able to receive an `abc.jpg` and save it in the file system, is there any documentation that can guide me towards that objective?

Comment: You should be able to extract an file in an HTTP request (normally a POST) just like any other variable. Looks like Klein is based on twisted, so maybe [this persons solution](http://www.cristinagreen.com/uploading-files-using-twisted-web.html) will work for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Liam Kelly` commented, the snippets from [this post](http://www.cristinagreen.com/uploading-files-using-twisted-web.html) should work. Using `cgi.FieldStorage` makes it possible to easily send file metadata without explicitly sending it. A Klein/Twisted approach would look something like this:

```
from cgi import FieldStorage
from klein import Klein
from werkzeug import secure_filename

app = Klein()

@app.route('/')
def formpage(request):
    return '''
    <form action="/images" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <p>
        Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br>
        <input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
    </p>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </div>
    </form>
    '''

@app.route('/images', methods=['POST'])
def processImages(request):
    method = request.method.decode('utf-8').upper()
    content_type = request.getHeader('content-type')

    img = FieldStorage(
        fp = request.content,
        headers = request.getAllHeaders(),
        environ = {'REQUEST_METHOD': method, 'CONTENT_TYPE': content_type})
    name = secure_filename(img[b'datafile'].filename)

    with open(name, 'wb') as fileOutput:
        # fileOutput.write(img['datafile'].value)
        fileOutput.write(request.args[b'datafile'][0])

app.run('localhost', 8000)
```

For whatever reason, my Python 3.4 (Ubuntu 14.04) version of `cgi.FieldStorage` doesn't return the correct results. I tested this on Python 2.7.11 and it works fine. With that being said, you could also collect the filename and other metadata on the frontend and send them in an ajax call to klein. This way you won't have to do too much processing on the backend (which is usually a good thing). Alternatively, you could figure out how to use the utilities provided by werkzeug. The functions `werkzeug.secure_filename` and `request.files` (ie. `FileStorage`) aren't particularly difficult to implement or recreate.